# How to adjust the length of the line added by line?

Tags: tables

I have the following latex code:

```latex
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{\textbf{Summary of the Treatment Assignment}\footnotemark}
\hline\hline
\label{treatment}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
Audit Range & Follow-up & Crisis & In Calif. & Out of Calif. &  Total        \\
\hline
Jan 1998 - Aug 1999 & Jul 1998 - May 2000 & 0 & 282  & 1305 & 1587 \\
Sep 1999 - Dec 1999 & Mar 2000 - Sep 2000 & NA& 29   & 261 & NA   \\
Jan 2000 - Jun 2000 & Jul 2000 - Mar 2001 & 1 &106   & 388 & 494 \\
\hline
Total               &                     &   & 388  & 1693 & 2081    
\end{tabular}
\hline\hline  
\end{table}
```

My problem is that the double lines that I create with the \hline\hline do not seem to cover up the entire row. They fall short.

I would appreciate if you can point out what I am doing wrong here.

Best,

Answer (score 1):

The lines fall short because that's your actual page margins. The tabular environment by default doesn't care about the right margin. If the table gets too wide it will start exceeding to the right. The horizontal lines within tabular will still fit the table, but outside the environment they will cling to the page margins again.
To fix this you need to narrow the table until it fits the page. Drop the \centering and add a \hskip in front of it to align it like this:

```
\hskip -10mm\begin{tabular}{...
```

And you're supposed to use \hrule outside the tabular environment not \hline.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `\hline` outside `tabular` environment. Use it inside as I did below. Since your table is wider than text width, it protrudes in to the right margin. To center it, put it in a box of width equal to text width. Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sym}[1]{\ensuremath{^{#1}}}   %% Thanks to egreg
\caption{\textbf{Summary of the Treatment Assignment}\protect\footnotemark}
\label{treatment}
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\hline\hline
Audit Range & Follow-up & Crisis & In Calif. & Out of Calif. &  Total        \\
\hline
Jan 1998 - Aug 1999 & Jul 1998 - May 2000 & 0 & 282  & 1305 & 1587 \\
Sep 1999 - Dec 1999 & Mar 2000 - Sep 2000 & NA& 29   & 261 & NA   \\
Jan 2000 - Jun 2000 & Jul 2000 - Mar 2001 & 1 &106   & 388 & 494 \\
\hline
Total               &                     &   & 388  & 1693 & 2081\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You already did good by not using vertical lines. Further, I suggest to use the `booktabs` package. This provides the lines with variable thickness so that you can get rid of double lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sym}[1]{\ensuremath{^{#1}}}   %% Thanks to egreg
\caption{\textbf{Summary of the Treatment Assignment}\protect\footnotemark}
\label{treatment}
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\toprule[1pt]
Audit Range & Follow-up & Crisis & In Calif. & Out of Calif. &  Total        \\
\midrule
Jan 1998 - Aug 1999 & Jul 1998 - May 2000 & 0 & 282  & 1305 & 1587 \\
Sep 1999 - Dec 1999 & Mar 2000 - Sep 2000 & NA& 29   & 261 & NA   \\
Jan 2000 - Jun 2000 & Jul 2000 - Mar 2001 & 1 &106   & 388 & 494 \\
\midrule
Total               &                     &   & 388  & 1693 & 2081\\
\bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, `\def\sym...` should really be `\DeclareRobustCommand{\sym}[1]{\ensuremath{^{#1}}}`

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I have added it in the code. Never noticed that part though. :)